# Interpolate and animate two svg path

Tags: animation, svg, interpolation

I have two svg path curves that I want to animate.
I want that in 5 seconds `dPathBefore` becomes `dPathNow` with a smooth animation transition.

That is my code:

```
const dPathBefore = 'M 50 350 Q 150 0 200 250 Q 250 350 300 250 C 350 200 450 250 400 350 Z'
const dPathNow = 'M 50 350 C 50 150 150 150 250 300 C 300 150 400 150 400 350 Z'

export class PathAnimation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <svg width={500} height={400} className={'ba b--black'}>
        <path d={dPathBefore} fill={'cyan'} fillOpacity={0.5} />
        <path d={dPathNow} fill={'red'} fillOpacity={0.5} />
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

I read [that article](http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=741) and I tried to do that:

```
<path d={dPathBefore}>
  <animate
    dur={'5s'}
    repeatCount={'indefinite'}
    attributeName={'d'}
    values={`${dPathNow};${dPathBefore};${dPathNow};`}
  />
</path>
```

That produce:

[image]

The result is not acceptable to me. The red curve is expected to become the blue one in a slow way. There should be an interpolation between the two so they have been to animated.
I have never done  a thing similar to that so I don't know where to start.

I have no preference on how to do this. I can use Javascript, CSS, SVG, ...

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me

---

A two possible paths are:

```
M504,217.96837758046047L489.59781879350896,217.05585884731812L470.86363307560316,214.2021740591243L455.24935650686257,209.88898669246805L442.67616275831006,204.52579180948993L432.5944768620284,198.43751290445206L424.4076807324568,191.85175297774788L417.62321391335945,184.92109353338404L411.87012300262165,177.7474756349613L406.876559933356,170.40012929754275L402.4429368598935,162.92731775668844L398.4201589437205,155.36378367845086L394.693739903777,147.73548290048342L391.1725185650579,140.06266051775228L387.78055397450754,132.3619264061584L384.4510660137251,124.6477375137062L381.1215780529427,116.933548621254L377.72961346239236,109.2328145096601L374.2083921236733,101.55999212692899L370.4819730837299,93.93169134896155L366.4591951675568,86.36815727072396L362.0255720940944,78.89534572986962L357.03200902482877,71.54799939245105L351.278918114091,64.37438149402831L344.4944512949937,57.443722049664444L336.30765516542243,50.85796212296023L326.2259692691408,44.76968321792228L313.65277552058853,39.40648833494413L298.03849895184834,35.09330096828778L279.3043132339424,32.23961618009379L258.451066013725,31.2327292526072L237.59781879351084,32.23961618009349L218.8636330756046,35.09330096828717L203.2493565068637,39.40648833494333L190.67616275831108,44.76968321792134L180.5944768620291,50.857962122959165L172.40768073245744,57.443722049663336L165.62321391335996,64.37438149402718L159.87012300262202,71.54799939244992L154.8765599333564,78.8953457298685L150.4429368598938,86.36815727072283L146.4201589437207,93.93169134896044L142.69373990377724,101.55999212692791L139.1725185650581,109.23281450965906L135.7805539745077,116.93354862125298L132.4510660137253,124.64773751370521L129.12157805294288,132.36192640615744L125.72961346239249,140.06266051775137L122.2083921236734,147.7354829004825L118.48197308372997,155.36378367845L114.45919516755694,162.92731775668761L110.02557209409443,170.40012929754198L105.03200902482891,177.7474756349606L99.27891811409114,184.92109353338338L92.49445129499384,191.85175297774725L84.3076551654224,198.43751290445152L74.22596926914088,204.52579180948948L61.65277552058859,209.88898669246763L46.03849895184814,214.20217405912402L27.304313233942423,217.055858847318L6.451066013724983,218.06274577480457L6.451066013724983,218.06274577480457L0,217.96837758046047L0,190.55329757211615L0,163.13821756377183L0,135.7231375554275L0,108.3080575470832L0,80.89297753873888L0,53.47789753039454L0,26.06281752205024L0,-1.3522624862941086L252,-1.3522624862941086L504,-1.3522624862941086L504,26.06281752205024L504,53.47789753039454L504,80.89297753873888L504,108.3080575470832L504,135.7231375554275L504,163.13821756377183L504,190.55329757211615Z
```

and:

```
M0,198.47868323936274L4.927028427960408,206.02871397201466L11.93725138272032,213.71099149842013L22.20984708937999,221.034554053252L38.419917256266814,227.6527556580375L65.18825228558191,232.7633822265229L104.68485444720656,234.82977872657665L104.68485444720656,234.82977872657665L144.18145660882874,232.7633822265232L170.94979163814477,227.652755658038L187.15986180503202,221.03455405325258L197.4324575116921,213.71099149842075L204.4426804664522,206.02871397201534L209.55669285362313,198.14571060477368L213.49875943621376,190.14123492852747L216.6785335463443,182.0587480265382L219.34296743530004,173.9239532585937L221.64982920279115,165.75306376812097L223.7054669341448,157.55691088670665L225.58541432472487,149.34313699247687L227.3463210486864,141.11744544980337L229.03330750837762,132.8843621970575L230.68485444720648,124.64773751370622L232.33640138603536,116.41111283035495L234.02338784572657,108.17802957760907L235.7842945696881,99.9523380349356L237.6642419602681,91.7385641407058L239.71987969162174,83.54241125929147L242.02674145911286,75.37152176881874L244.69117534806858,67.23672700087423L247.87094945819908,59.154240098884955L251.81301604078962,51.149764422638725L256.9270284279605,43.26676105539707L263.9372513827204,35.58448352899161L274.2098470893801,28.26092097415973L290.4199172562667,21.642719369374305L317.18825228558194,16.532092800888876L356.6848544472066,14.465696300835148L396.18145660882567,16.532092800888222L422.9497916381429,21.642719369373268L439.15986180503097,28.26092097415861L449.4324575116914,35.58448352899036L456.4426804664517,43.26676105539579L461.55669285362274,51.1497644226374L465.4987594362135,59.15424009888365L468.67853354634417,67.23672700087295L471.3429674352999,75.37152176881747L473.64982920279107,83.54241125929025L475.70546693414474,91.73856414070463L477.58541432472487,99.95233803493443L479.3463210486864,108.17802957760796L481.03330750837756,116.41111283035387L482.6848544472064,124.64773751370517L484.3364013860353,132.88436219705648L486.0233878457266,141.11744544980237L487.78429456968803,149.3431369924759L489.6642419602681,157.55691088670574L491.7198796916217,165.75306376812011L494.0267414591128,173.92395325859286L496.69117534806855,182.05874802653742L499.87094945819905,190.14123492852673L503.8130160407896,198.145710604773L504,198.47868323936274L504,224.5632103765343L504,250.6477375137059L252,250.6477375137059L0,250.6477375137059L0,224.5632103765343Z
```

But it is not me who create them, is an external application that return them to me and they can be extremely different between them.

Answer (score 5):

The d attribute for the paths has to have the same commands. I've rewritten your paths and now it works. I hope this helps.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:100vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "30 120 400 250">

  <path d="M50.000, 350.000 
          C116.667, 116.667 166.667, 83.333 200.000, 250.000 
          C233.333, 316.667 266.667, 316.667 300.000, 250.000 
          C350.000, 200.000 450.000, 250.000 400.000, 350.000 Z">
  <animate
    dur='5s'
    attributeType="XML"
    attributeName='d'      
    repeatCount='indefinite'
    
           values="M50.000, 350.000 
          C116.667, 116.667 166.667, 83.333 200.000, 250.000 
          C233.333, 316.667 266.667, 316.667 300.000, 250.000 
          C350.000, 200.000 450.000, 250.000 400.000, 350.000 Z;
                   
          M50.000, 350.000 
          C50.000, 150.000 150.000, 150.000 250.000, 300.000 
          C300.000, 150.000 400.000, 150.000 400.000, 349.999 
          C400.000, 349.999 400.000, 350.000 400.000, 350.000 Z;
                   
           M50.000, 350.000 
          C116.667, 116.667 166.667, 83.333 200.000, 250.000 
          C233.333, 316.667 266.667, 316.667 300.000, 250.000 
          C350.000, 200.000 450.000, 250.000 400.000, 350.000 Z"
  />
    
    <animate 
             attributeName="fill"
             dur="5s" 
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="red;gold;red"
    />
             
    </path>
 
    <!--
<path id='PathBefore' d= 'M 50 350 Q 150 0 200 250 Q 250 350 300 250 C 350 200 450 250 400 350 Z'/>
<path  id='PathNow' d= 'M 50 350 C 50 150 150 150 250 300 C 300 150 400 150 400 350 Z'/>-->   

</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP updated their question so I'm updating my answer:
I see those paths are practically polylines. Apparently the only command used apart of `M` and `Z` is `L`

In this case the simplest way to achieve what you want would be by programming those paths to have the same number of points.

If this is not possible, the easier way would be by reducing the number of points of the first path (from 80 t0 68). For this you need to split the `d` string into an array of points `path.split("L")` and remove every 6th or so. Next you join the points back into a string to be used as a `d` attribute.

An other way would be adding points to the second path (from 68 to 80). To do this you will need to split the `d` string into an array of points, and every n points you need to add a point in between. Then again you join the points back into a string to be used as a `d` attribute or for the `values` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My paths were only an example. How do I make the two paths with the same commands?

Comment: You may read about [Morphing in SVG - first steps](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/morphing-in-svg-first-steps) and [Morphing in SVG - part #2](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/preparing-the-paths-for-morphing-in-svg). Also you may take a look at this: [SVG-in-C](https://github.com/enxaneta/SVG-in-C). However if your paths are using the `A` or `a` commands my code won't do, and you may want to search for an other way to do it. As an idea: Illustrator will take yous `A` and `a` commands and transform them to Bézier curves.

Comment: I will read articles you linked me. Anyway I updated my main question

Comment: Apparently your paths have only `L` commands. If this is true, you have 80 commands in the first path and only 68 in the second. (I've made a `split`). In this case you may want to add the 12 missing lines for example in Illustrator. And this should work. You don't need to transform them in `C`

Comment: The process should be automated, i can't use Illustrator

Comment: What do you mean by "should be automated"? You need to do it dynamically?

Comment: @enxaneta Congratulations on the round number. Your answers are always interesting and useful.

Comment: @enxaneta yes, the path are generated according to the position of the sun therefore may change at any time and can also be very different between them

Comment: @CarlRouge I've updated my answer and and I won't update it any more. From a simple question it became extremely complex. If you consider I've answered your question please accept it. If you need to ask something else please ask a different question and I'll be glad to help.