# How to do morphing in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working with svg animation right now. I want to setup morph animation on this svg. For example the vibe icon will be morph with Wibe on hover of the image. I try few examples from the stackoverflow. But that is not working. Right now the current animation on this image is rotating E of wibe and floating vibe icon.

Please help me regarding this issue. How can I use morph animation in this.

Thanks

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 1491.3333 803.33069"
   height="500"
   width="700"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1" style="
    background-color: #000;
"><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6"><clipPath
       id="clipPath18"
       clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path
         id="path16"
         d="M 0,602.498 H 1118.496 V 0 H 0 Z" /></clipPath></defs><g
     transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,803.33067)"
     id="g10"><g
       id="g12"><g
         clip-path="url(#clipPath18)"
         id="g14"><g
           transform="translate(665.3598,379.7295)"
           id="g20"><path
             id="path22"
             style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
             d="m 0,0 h 26.962 c 13.938,0 23.293,3.023 28.064,9.077 4.763,6.046 7.149,12.378 7.149,18.979 0,6.235 -2.475,12.003 -7.427,17.33 C 49.789,50.705 40.72,53.36 27.517,53.36 23.481,53.36 18.8,53.262 13.481,53.083 8.17,52.902 3.676,52.625 0,52.265 Z m 0,-57.764 v -56.668 c 1.111,0 4.044,-0.18 8.807,-0.548 4.772,-0.367 11.193,-0.547 19.257,-0.547 15.409,0 26.407,2.566 33.001,7.696 6.609,5.139 9.91,12.296 9.91,21.456 0,3.675 -0.638,7.246 -1.921,10.727 -1.29,3.481 -3.578,6.512 -6.879,9.085 -3.301,2.565 -7.891,4.673 -13.758,6.316 -5.859,1.658 -13.563,2.483 -23.098,2.483 z m -91.859,165.587 c 7.337,1.095 15.769,2.108 25.303,3.023 9.535,0.923 19.25,1.74 29.152,2.483 9.911,0.728 19.535,1.276 28.882,1.643 9.355,0.368 17.509,0.548 24.486,0.548 45.843,0 80.134,-6.504 102.872,-19.527 22.738,-13.016 34.103,-33.278 34.103,-60.787 0,-13.931 -3.203,-25.761 -9.625,-35.483 -6.414,-9.715 -15.131,-18.057 -26.129,-25.034 15.402,-5.506 28.057,-13.383 37.959,-23.645 9.91,-10.278 14.854,-24.756 14.854,-43.473 0,-33.728 -12.468,-57.104 -37.411,-70.134 -24.937,-13.016 -61.793,-19.528 -110.569,-19.528 -12.836,0 -29.617,0.458 -50.337,1.373 -20.727,0.923 -41.898,2.851 -63.54,5.784 z m -25.049,-282.757 c -9.535,-1.47 -18.154,-2.573 -25.859,-3.3 -7.697,-0.743 -14.666,-1.111 -20.9,-1.111 -6.233,0 -13.21,0.368 -20.907,1.111 -7.704,0.727 -16.129,1.83 -25.296,3.3 v 283.852 c 8.057,1.838 16.031,3.121 23.923,3.848 7.892,0.743 15.491,1.111 22.828,1.111 6.969,0 14.494,-0.368 22.55,-1.111 8.072,-0.727 15.957,-2.01 23.661,-3.848 z m -237.89,119.924 34.102,163.928 c 2.941,0.735 8.62,1.463 17.06,2.206 8.439,0.727 17.426,1.095 26.961,1.095 12.1,0 22.828,-0.368 32.182,-1.095 9.348,-0.743 16.039,-1.471 20.076,-2.206 l -89.129,-283.304 c -6.234,-1.838 -13.016,-3.031 -20.345,-3.578 -7.344,-0.548 -14.674,-0.818 -22.003,-0.818 -7.344,0 -14.771,0.27 -22.287,0.818 -7.51,0.547 -15.304,1.74 -23.376,3.578 l -40.157,154.034 c -6.969,-24.576 -14.028,-50.427 -21.184,-77.569 -7.15,-27.141 -14.029,-52.625 -20.631,-76.465 -7.697,-1.838 -15.311,-3.031 -22.827,-3.578 -7.518,-0.548 -14.944,-0.818 -22.273,-0.818 -7.344,0 -14.674,0.27 -22.011,0.818 -7.336,0.547 -14.118,1.74 -20.352,3.578 l -86.368,283.304 c 4.029,0.735 11.095,1.463 21.178,2.206 10.083,0.727 21.177,1.095 33.278,1.095 9.535,0 18.799,-0.368 27.786,-1.095 8.987,-0.743 14.936,-1.471 17.877,-2.206 l 35.761,-168.332 39.609,168.332 c 6.234,1.838 13.113,3.031 20.63,3.586 7.509,0.54 14.936,0.825 22.273,0.825 7.336,0 14.763,-0.285 22.287,-0.825 7.517,-0.555 15.124,-1.748 22.821,-3.586 z" /></g><g
           transform="translate(220.8446,208.5321)"
           id="g24"><path
             id="path26"
             style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
             d="M 0,0 C 62.399,-4.247 111.294,-96.425 205.706,-86.576 172.84,-130.659 92.497,-208.532 24.911,-208.532 -117.925,-208.532 -130.651,8.887 0,0" /> <animateMotion
              path="M10,50 q60,50 100,0 q60,-50 100,0"
              begin="g10.mouseover" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" end="g10.mouseout" 
              /></g><g
           transform="translate(580.4182,121.9514)"
           id="g28"><path
             id="path30"
             style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
             d="M 0,0 C -85.441,36.938 -117.17,22.297 -153.931,0 -105.978,83.683 -54.72,98.899 0,0" /> <animateMotion
              path="M10,50 q60,50 100,0 q60,-50 100,0"
              begin="g10.mouseover" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" end="g10.mouseout"
              /></g><g
           transform="translate(653.5858,147.7134)"
           id="g32"><path
             id="path34"
             style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
             d="M 0,0 C -13.413,-15.054 -31.372,-29.682 -73.072,-25.757 -16.196,-124.558 53.294,-118.125 91.542,-83.726 164.849,-17.787 68.09,76.417 0,0" /> <animateMotion
              path="M10,50 q60,50 100,0 q60,-50 100,0"
              begin="g10.mouseover" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" end="g10.mouseout"
              /></g><g
           transform="translate(925.3088,392.7031)"
           id="g36"><path
             id="path38"
             style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
             d="m 0,0 c 0,0 0,41.564 40.817,43.368 40.271,1.78 44.37,-43.33 44.37,-43.33 z M 81.95,103.607 C -68.673,133.163 -111.656,-7.91 -72.935,-117.879 c 0,0 48.014,-94.48 168.825,-63.503 l -1.549,75.894 c 0,0 -80.541,-21.684 -86.736,37.172 l 159.346,2.403 c 0,0 34.441,146.082 -85.001,169.52" /><animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="360 8.4 9.5" to="0 8.4 9.5" dur="0.5s" additive="sum" begin="g10.mouseover" repeatCount="1" end="g10.mouseout" /></g></g></g></g>
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: By morphing  I understand a path that is changing it's shape in something else. For this you will need a initial value attribute and the morphed value for the `d` attribute. Please take a look at this answer. Maybe it's what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791442/interpolate-and-animate-two-svg-path/53791871#53791871

Comment: This guy has some good svg tutorials on the site. In this one he also works with morphing by using SMIL https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/23-animating-svg-smil/